# Angular NGRX split large array to chunks and combine API requests results

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

So the problem is that I have a large array of objects, let's say a 1000 that I need to send to our API in NGRX Effect and then dispatch a new Action with the response, but API takes too long to process such a large requests at once, so I want to divide this array into smaller chunks, send a request with each of them one after another and then combine responses from all of them into a single action. I've tried it with mapping this large array of data into an array of Observables with `from()` operator, but couldn't figure out what to use next after it was mapped, I've tried casting it to Promises and use Promise.all() on them but again, no luck. In summary what I need to do is this:

1. Action triggers an Effect that needs to send API call with an array of data from Action,
2. In the Effect, array of data gets divided into chunks of 100 objects,
3. These chunks are mapped into API requests, sent one after another, and the response from each needs to be combined with previous ones,
4. After all of these requests are done, an Action with the combined response from them needs to be dispatched to update Store.

Here is a simplified Effect that I'm using currently and what I need to divide is `action.rows`:

```
loadRows$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(RowsActions.LoadRows),
    switchMap((action) => {
      return this.eventsService.getBatchRows(action.rows).pipe(
        switchMap((response) => {
          return [
            new RowsLoaded({ rows: response.rows }),
            new LoadedTableData(response.rows),
          ];
        }),
        catchError(() => {
          return of(new RowsFailedToLoad());
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question and place `code` in code blocks correctly, your `});` is outisde the code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have implemented similiar logic,
if one chunk will have 100 items - it still to big number.

I am running ALL items paralelly.

**UPD:**

if you will change `mergeMap` to `concatMap` - all calls will be **sequential**

it does not matter if it is single row or chunk of rows

```
        from(action.rows)
            .pipe(
                mergeMap(id => api(id).pipe(catchError(e => EMPTY))),
                toArray())
             )
```

here is working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rxjs-playground-forked-u8c7jd?file=/src/index.js

FINAL VERSION:

```
const { of, from } = require("rxjs");
const {
  switchMap,
  concatMap,
  toArray,
  catchError,
  map,
  tap
} = require("rxjs/operators");

const chunkArray = (arr, size) =>
  arr.length > size
    ? [arr.slice(0, size), ...chunkArray(arr.slice(size), size)]
    : [arr];
const getBatchRows = (rows) => of({ response: { rows } });

of({ rows: ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5"] })
  .pipe(
    switchMap((action) =>
      from(chunkArray(action.rows, 2))
        .pipe(
          concatMap((rows) =>
            getBatchRows(rows).pipe(catchError((e) => of({})))
          )
        )
        .pipe(toArray())
    ),

    tap((data) => console.log(data)),
    map((responseArray) => responseArray.map((i) => i.response.rows).flat()),
    map(rows => [
      new RowsLoaded({ rows }),
      new LoadedTableData(rows),
    ])
  )
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

to use chunk way - almost nothing to do

will use

```
const chunkArray = (arr, size) =>
  arr.length > size
    ? [arr.slice(0, size), ...chunkArray(arr.slice(size), size)]
    : [arr];
```

and use here:

```
 from(chunkArray(action.rows, 100))

//and change this
 mergeMap(rows => this.eventsService.getBatchRows(rows)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for, doing it this way send all requests at the same time, but what I need do is send one, wait for it to finish, then send another one until all chunks are resolved

Comment: just change `mergeMap` to `concatMap`

Comment: I've tried concatMap, it sends the first chunk and doesn't send the rest of them
EDIT: ok, had a small error, concatMap instead of mergeMap send them one after another, but it also sends an action after each, what I want it to do is wait for all of them to finish and then send an action with all rows combined

Comment: It's hard to code without editor)) please attach reproducible app, I believe we need to put `toArray()` before `  map(responseArray => responseArray.map(i => i.response.rows)),`

Comment: I mean to remove toArray that stands near concatMap, and add toArray after switchMap

Comment: Well it's quite a large app so it's not easy to extract just enough to make a working thing, but I've added toArray() before final switch map and it resulted in not entering the switchMap and not sending an action after resolving all requests

Comment: Can you attach what you are getting before and after toArray?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244028/discussion-between-shutsman-and-grhu).